# GeoJson element rendered using D3 not scaling correctly on Leaflet map

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to follow the instructions from Mike Bostock, getting D3 data to show on leaflet: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/ . I have implemented the code correctly and gotten the d3 geoJson data of Louisiana coastlines onto a leaflet map, but when the map is zoomed, the geojson layer does not scale correctly (I want to use d3 vs leaflet to load the data as I want to be able to animate the data, which is easier in d3)

I have gotten the core code working, and have set the CSS exactly like in the Bostock example. I have initalised the map and added the base maps.

```
var map;

map = L.map('map', {center: [29.50655, -90.29388], zoom: 9});

L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
    maxZoom: 13,
}).addTo(map);

var CartoDB_PositronOnlyLabels = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
    subdomains: 'abcd',
    maxZoom: 19
}).addTo(map);
```

```
var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide");

d3.json("../shoreline-changes/data/LAshorelinesGEOJSON.geojson", function(json) {


    var transform = d3.geoTransform({point: projectPoint}),
        path = d3.geoPath().projection(transform);


    var feature = g.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter().append("path");

    map.on("viewreset", reset);
    reset();

    // Reposition the SVG to cover the features.
    function reset() {
            bounds = path.bounds(json);
            var topLeft = bounds[0],
                bottomRight = bounds[1];

        svg .attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
            .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
            .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
            .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

        g   .attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");

        feature.attr("d", path)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("stroke-width", "1")
            .attr("stroke", function(json)
            {if (json.properties.year == "1853")
            {return "blue"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1855")
            {return "yellow"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1869")
            {return "red"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1877")
            {return "green"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1883")
            {return "black"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1884")
            {return "grey"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1887")
            {return "orange"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1922")
            {return "teal"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1932")
            {return "#0bfdff"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1973")
            {return "#ff06f9"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1978")
            {return "#ffc106"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "1996")
            {return "#4a4d57"}
            else if(json.properties.year == "2001")
            {return "#014020"}
            });
        console.log(json);
    }
    // Use Leaflet to implement a D3 geometric transformation.
    function projectPoint(x, y) {
        // Returns the map layer point that corresponds to the given geographical coordinates
        var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
        this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
    }



});
```

CSS is:

```
#map {
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
}

svg {
    position: relative;
}
```

A working example can be seen here: https://experiments.lmmapping.com/projects/shoreline-changes/index.html, or the codepen (which isnt showing the geojson data despite showing in the console): https://codepen.io/datatpolymer/full/GRKGjgp.

And as you can see when zooming, the geojson data does not scale correctly and any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something is wrong with how the code pen is applying your stroke (if you set it to something plain it should show). I managed to get the zoom working by changing the event which triggers redraw - though to be honest, I'm not entirely sure why this alone should be sufficient: `map.on("zoomend", reset);`. I'd save fork the codepen, but you now need an account to save anything apparently...

Comment: can you just paste the code here please?

Comment: Other changing the codepen to show a stroke (`.attr("stroke","#fff")`), which appears to address an issue in code pen only, the only change I made was changing `map.on("viewreset",...` to `map.on("zoomend",...`. I'd rather not post an answer to show the changes on this one line as I'm not sure why one event type works and the other does not or if this is a good solution. Perhaps, hopefully, someone more familiar with Leaflet will be able to elaborate on the distinction between the event types.

Comment: hm i cant replicate that in my code locally. The geojson still scales incorrectly, but on codepen it seems to work. Having the stroke colour is kinda important for what im doing so will have to find another work around. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but adding for completeness and posterity:

As others have found out, changing the triggering event for Leaflet from "viewreset" to "zoomend" was effective. I suffered from a similar issue that landed me here, and looked into the Leaflet docs for both events.

It seems that perhaps when viewreset is triggered, Leaflet doesn't yet have the correct information to give D3, thus D3 scales the SVG prior to all changes being made to Leaflet's underlying map, so the SVG is updated with old or incomplete information.

**viewreset:**

> Fired when the map needs to redraw its content (this usually happens on map zoom or load). Very useful for creating custom overlays.

**zoomend:**

> Fired when the map has changed, after any animations.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-viewreset

It's also possible this is the result of API changes since 7 years ago when Bostock's D3 + Leaflet (D3 V3) tutorial was published. There's quite a few tweaks required in just the D3 bits to follow that tutorial for V4 and V5.